# App Insights Analytics rename legend based on condition

Tags: azure-application-insights

If I were using the analytic querying ability is it possible to re-label the legend based on a custom condition? For example, I want to categorize exceptions based on their sub-type. For example, a Sql Exception could be down to a timeout, insufficient privileges etc. The only way to do this I found was via a query like this:

```
exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(7d) and outerType contains "SqlException"
| project 
    ['SqlException'] = outerType,
    timestamp,
    outerMethod   
| summarize count(['SqlException']) by bin(timestamp, 1d), outerMethod
| render timechart
```

Trouble is the legend is quite "wordy" and was wondering whether I could use a "case when" approach and re-label the legend based on a condition (via examining the text). Granted this could be slow but if there is a more efficient way then please feel free to suggest an alternative. From looking at the API reference I couldn't find one but I have limited experience with this at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [iff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#iff) keyword.

Here's an example:

```
exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(7d) and outerType contains "SqlException"
| project 
    ['SqlException'] = outerType,
    timestamp,
    outerMethod
| extend reason = iff(outerMethod has "timeout", "timeout", "other")
| summarize count(['SqlException']) by bin(timestamp, 1d), reason
| render timechart
```